# Runge-Kutta methods for complex valued differential equations

Tags: complex-integration, interpolation, runge-kutta-methods

As I understand it, RK methods are based on integrating a polynomial spline. I'm unsure if I can use them for the Schrödinger wave equation as I can't think of what it would mean to interpolate across a complex domain. I know it's not right to say $C=R^2$ but either way I still don't understand how one would interpolate over R^2 into R^2. Beyond asking if the method is valid, I'd like to know what other questions I should be asking about interpolation overall.

Comment: Runge-Kutta methods work for ODE, you are considering a PDE. Do you apply the method of lines? Then the values in the domain are not only complex, they are functions (of space if you integrate over time).

Comment: Yes, so when I solve PDE's numerically I solve systems of ODE's for each point integrating over time on a finite grid or mesh. I looked up the method of lines and this appears to be equivalent. So if I wanted all points in the domain they would be functions like $|x|=a$ for $a\in R^+$? Or is the choice of curve important? I haven't taken a complex analysis course and the undergraduate one at my university is severely lacking so I probably won't learn this in a formal setting for another 2 years.

Answer (score 2):

The Runge-Kutta formulas for a complex-valued function are exactly the same as for a real-valued function.  It's just that you do the arithmetic with complex numbers.  The **independent** variable, however, is still real.